# Searching through a .js file using Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a .js file that looks as shown (shortened for simplfication)

```
var albums=
"tracks":[
            {"title":"Dunnock","mp3":"Birdsong-Dunnock.mp3",
            "lyrics":"The Dunnock or hedge sparrow has a fast warbling song often delivered from the top of a hedge or bush"}
            {"title":"Robin","mp3":"Birdsong-Robin.mp3",
           "lyrics":"Unusually among British birds, both the male and the femaale robins sing"},

]
```

I need to make a function that looks through the file and allows me to select one of the songs, given that keywords have been found in it. What I have so far is:

This function takes a string, looks through the file using a loop, and for now, alerts the name of the song(s) if it's been found

```
function searchIt("str") {
  for (var i in list) {
    if(albums[i].lyrics.indexOf(str)){
      alert(albums.tracks.title)
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am quite stuck. Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You should always make sure that you don't have syntax errors. Those errors are reported in the console. The syntax error you have is in `function searchIt("str")`, it should be `function searchIt(str)`. Beside that [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `-1` if the string does not contain the `searchElement`

Comment: is albums an object or an array? if it's an object you're missing the braces `{}`. if it's an array you don't need the 'tracks' key.

Comment: what is that `list` variable? you haven't defined it. did you mean `albums`? or `albums.tracks`?

Comment: your if condition `albums[i].lyrics.indexOf(str)` will always return a truthy value. if you want to check if str is in albums[i].lyrics, use `albums[i].lyrics.indexOf(str) >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

You had a bunch of syntax errors in there, you should read about object notation and arrays on MDN.

I got it to work like this

```
var tracks = [
            {
             title:"Dunnock",
             mp3:"Birdsong-Dunnock.mp3",
             lyrics:"The Dunnock or hedge sparrow has a fast warbling song often delivered from the top of a hedge or bush"
            },
            {
             title:"Robin",
             mp3 :"Birdsong-Robin.mp3",
             lyrics :"Unusually among British birds, both the male and the femaale robins sing"
            }
]

function searchIt(str) {
  for (i=0; i<tracks.length; i++) {
    if(tracks[i].lyrics.indexOf(str) >= 0){
      alert(tracks[i].title);
    }
  }
}

searchIt("Unusually");
```

So after I formatted the syntax errors away in the array, i used a for loop ( i think you were trying to use "for each" which I'm not very familiar with yet). I iterated through the array, and asked if (str) matched anything in "lyrics" of each element of the array, and if it does, it would return 0 or greater. If not, it would be -1. So if it matched my condition, then it would return the title of the track.

Heres the doc for the indexOf method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Thanks for the elp

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm trying to load the `tracks[i].title` into a textbox. I wrote `document.getElementById("show") = tracks[i].title;`. The html code is `<input id="show">`. This doesn't seem to working though, Can you spot what's wrong?

Comment: Np! If you thought that helped I'd appreciate an upvote. Let me look at it for a bit

Comment: @Pete I only know how to do it in jQuery, here's the link, last one I posted was bad https://jsfiddle.net/bushido/07o6j3a6/4/

Comment: I should add, I don't think you can replace stuff in an input bux, as far as i know.

Comment: @Pete I'd appreciate it if you marked the question answered if this was what you were looking for, thanks.